# Is it possible to configure one active directory to fallback account verification to another one?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Let's say I have two active directories: AD-1 and AD-2 and I want to obtain the following behaviour:

When someone tries to do a LDAP search on the AD-2 for authentication to check AD-2 database first and if the user is not found to delegate it to AD-1.

This has to be transparent for the client trying to verify the credentials.

Reasoning: I have some web application that are using LDAP autentication and checking the AD-2 server. AD-1 would be the main corporate one, one that I cannot control, but the AD-2 is under my control.

I need to be able to add users to AD-2, users that are not in AD-1. Still any user frm AD-1 cand be considered as valid for AD-2.

AD-2 contains users from outside the company.

Note: I have minimal experience configuring AD.

Comment: Please tell us what you're trying to achieve by this, and why?

Comment: AD doesn't work like that. As @Dan says: tell us what the actual problem that you are trying to solve is. There's probably a much better way to handle it.

Comment: No. Stop that. You're hurting the servers.

Comment: Your application would have to support searching multiple LDAP directories, and your user would have to supply which directory they're logging into as, or else there'd be no way to know that jsmith existing on both directories is the one trying to log in to the application; it would end up hitting the first one and the second one would never work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is at least not something already present in Active Directory. Quite to the contrary - when doing authentication against Kerberos or LDAP, you have to explicitly specify the distinguished name of your logon user - which would include the domain name of the same. Any kind of "fallback" would be ineffectual in this case since the explicitly specified domain name "ad1" would not match "ad2" and the authentication would fail when queried against ad2 servers in any case.

The only way to achieve the kind of "directory union" you want is to use an overlay / abstraction above the employed directories to do two searches - one for each directory. If you can modify your web applications, you probably would implement an API to do so, otherwise you would need to implement some kind of proxy service for authentication with this functionality.

The common approach to this kind of problem is called "identity management", although the intended direction - unification of all user-related data and single-sign-on for all applications - is quite the opposite of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that you would have to handle at the application level. If your app makes authentication calls to the ADs, you simply code your app to use both as an authentication source and prefix the username with the proper domain name at each iteration.

There is no native AD functionality for this.

Answer (score 0):

We accomplished a similar solution by creating AD2 as a child domain of AD1 (ex: ad2.ad1.com).  This allows us to add users from the parent domain to groups in the child domain and thereby allow accounts from both to authenticate to the application.

Keep in mind that this was done with full cooperation of the IT staff.  If fact, they developed the solution for application use.

A second possible solution is to add a crossRef object to your customer AD that would redirect or refer the authorization request to a secondary LDAP based on the name.  This would require you to pass along more than a login name to find the object..  More [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978014.aspx) on custom crossRef objects in AD.

Answer (score -1):

A one way trust could possibly be used to reach this end. I'm not sure but it should be possible to use a trust in conjunction with a read only domain controller from your internal domain. Failing that there are third party apps like Atlassians Crowd that provide single sign on against multiple directories.

EDIT - as pointed out the trust only works with fully qualified names. I found this worked well for my internal users as it was easy enough to request they include their domain names.

I have successfully used [Crowd](http://www.atlassian.com/software/crowd/overview) to merge multiple directories into a single interface. Not sure the specifics on your web app but this product (or one like it) may be a possibility.

Comment: That wouldn't work. When you log in from an `AD1` workstation as `user`, you're actually logging in as `ad1\user`. To log in to a domain that's part of a trust, you would have to specify `ad2\user` when logging on.

Comment: I get that.. What I don't get is why that wouldn't be acceptable here. If folks are using a fully qualified name when logging in - that is a common enough setup - that is already addressed.

Comment: Except that he's asking for a way that someone can just type `user` and then have his AD automatically try and authenticate `user` against `ad2` and if it fails fall back to `ad1`

Comment: That's interesting, the last answer, with negative votes contains the best info, crowd was already on my radar, because in my case I have to administer several Jira and Confluence instances. Still I think that Crowd should work for any web apps.

Comment: Yeah with a little work most webapps can be used with Crowd. My in house devs wish they had looked into crowd before they wrote their own single sign on app.